# determining subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

The following linear system

$7x+3y+z=3$

$4x+2y+z=2$

$x+y+z=1$

After I performed row reduction here is what I got

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 & -0.5 & 0 \\
0 & 1 & 1.5 & 1 \\
0 & 0 & 0 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$\vec x=\begin{bmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        z  \\
        \end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
        0 \\
        1 \\
        0  \\
        \end{bmatrix}+z\begin{bmatrix}
        0.5 \\
        -1.5 \\
        1  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$

How do I know whether or not it forms a subspace of $R^3$ or not?

The question is 
Do the solutions $\begin{bmatrix}
        x \\
        y \\
        z  \\
        \end{bmatrix}$ of this system form a subspace of $R^3$? explain.

Comment: You're looking at the nullspace of the system, but your system is not homogenous. You're missing a shift of $(0,1,0)$ for the solution space.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: i just added the original question

Comment: FYI: what you've got there is three planes and the solution is where they intersect. Usually, it is a point, but in this particular case they all pass through a common line $(3,5,6)/14+t(1,-3,2)$, where $t\in\mathbb R$. This line does not pass through the origin, so it is not a linear subspace.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution to the system is not a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$ :  the problem is that $0$ , meaning the $0$ vector $(0,0,0)$ must be part of any subspace, but it is not part of the solution to your equations, because $(0,0,0)$ is not a solution for $x+y+z=1$,( because  $+0+0+0=0 \neq 1$). Since $0$ is not part of your solution space, your solution space cannot be a subspace of $\mathbb R^3$. The best you can aim for is for the solution to be an affine space, affine subspace of $\mathbb R^3$.

Comment: did you mean the last row of the matrix? If so I understand now

Comment: @statstudent: yes, any subspace must contain $(0,0,0)$ , by closure properties of subspaces: if some vector $v$ belongs to  a subspace, then so does $tv$ , for any (Real, I assume ) constant $t$ . But the solution cannot contain $0:=(0,0,0)$ , since $0$ is not a solution for the bottom row.

Answer (score 0):

It will not be a subspace. You can see that (0.5,0.5,1) is in your solution set but 
2(0.5,0.5,1) is not there so scalar multiplication is violated.